# My table visual in Power BI doesn't show all the data

Tags: ms-access, powerbi, powerbi-datasource

My report is based on an MS Access file. I have a table visualization in Power BI that takes fields from different tables. The visual shows all the data when I add fields from all my tables, except when I try ti add fields from table 4. If I add fields from table 4, then the visual doesn't show the right data.

Any help would be great as I've been pulling my hair out over this for the past couple of hours!!!!

Say I have 3 tables Project , Part, and Material as such:

**Table Project:**

Project________Start__________End

A__________2019-07-20_______2019-12-01

B__________2019-07-21_______2019-12-02

C__________2019-07-22_______2019-12-03

**Table Part:**

Part Number_____Entry Date_______Exit Date__________Project

1______________2019-08-01______2019-08-02__________A

2______________2019-08-02_________________________B

3______________2019-08-03______2019-08-04__________C

**Table Material:**

Material_______Purchase Date_______Part Number

118____________2019-09-01____________1

509____________2019-09-02____________2

650____________2019-09-03____________3

650_________________________________3

When I try to create a table with the fields **Project, Part No, Entry, Exit**, it works just fine. However, when I try to add **Purchase Date**, or anything from this table (Material), the data doesn't show anymore.

My relationships are Project1:Part* // Part1:Material*.

Comment: Please provide sample data and show examples of what you mean.

Comment: I tried to illustrate as best I can...

Comment: I replicated your example and it worked fine for me. 

Table with **Project**, **Part No**, **Entry**, **Exit** and **Purchase Date**: http://prntscr.com/qlpx2t.


The Data Model: http://prntscr.com/qlpz15.


So you're right about pulling your hair, it doesn't make sense. Is there any other thing you can think of that could be causing that?

Also, remember to clear the cache, it might help.